# Launch test for non-terminating processes

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I'm using ROS2 Humble and Ubuntu 22.04 (through Docker, ros:humble).
I'm writing a system_tests package to run integration tests for my stack, which has features like teleop, mapping, navigation etc. The stack is of course a continuously running process.

I've found that the [launch_testing](https://github.com/ros2/launch) package was made for integration tests, and it has a lot of examples, but it doesn't mention non-terminating processes.
I tried to include the bringup launch file which launches my stack correctly but since it never terminates on its own, the test never returns.

Has anyone ever managed to implement these end-to-end / integration tests in ros?

Here is my minimal non-working example

````py
import rclpy

from threading import Thread
import unittest
import pytest
import launch_testing

from ament_index_python.packages \
    import get_package_share_directory as package_dir

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription

from my_interfaces.srv import MyMessage


@pytest.mark.launch_test
def generate_test_description() -> LaunchDescription:
    return LaunchDescription([
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                package_dir('bringup'), 'bringup.launch.py')),

        launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest(),
    ])


class TestMyCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        rclpy.init()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        rclpy.shutdown()

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.node = rclpy.create_node('test_my_case')
        self.spinner_thread = Thread(target=lambda: rclpy.spin(self.node))
        self.spinner_thread.start()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.node.destroy_node()

    def test_call_add_node(self) -> None:
        service_cli = self.node.create_client(MyMessage, '/my_service')

        self.assertTrue(service_cli.wait_for_service(10.),
                        "Service '/my_service' not available")

        req = MyMessage.Request()
        res: MyMessage.Response = service_cli.call(req)
        self.assertTrue(res.success, f'Service call failed: {res.message}')
```
````

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to a related question which might be usable here: [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/361087/launching-and-killing-nodes-within-a-python-node-in-ros-2-foxy/?answer=390435#post-id-390435).

Based on that answer:

```py
launch_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ros2", "launch", relative_path_to_launch_file], text=True)

# Run tests while process is running, then
# get this process handle in the tearDown method
# after the tests have finished
# (or simply wait for a set amount of time)

launch_process.send_signal(SIGINT)
launch_process.wait(timeout=30)
```

Also, I found [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/126) about this exact same problem.

Comment: Using subprocess shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Unless you have any other solution...